# proxy ajp single apache single glassfish multiple GF domains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, glassfish, mod-proxy-ajp

I'm sorry if I am not well versed enough to be as specific as some would wish here. I have successfully got Apache mod_proxy_ajp working with Glassfish 3.1.2 on a VPS. However it is one Apache httpd server connecting to a single domain on the Glassfish server via port 8009 (pretty standard it seems).

I would like to try to add another domain to the Glassfish server with a slightly different code base backing a different Apache virtual server, all on the same machine.  Is this possible and could someone give me some tips or instruction on where to start or what to do.

I learned how to get the connector set up for a single site on my own but can't find how to do this. This is running on a VPS by the way.